# Karate - how to set path to driver properly (executable)

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I use Karate paralel run and everything is OK when I use driver configuration:

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: '/Users/rabu/Downloads/geckodriver'});
```

But I need to change the executable URL from code above to:

1. project (driver is part of the test project), e.g.: "src/test/java/drivers/geckodriver"
2. HTTP/HTTPS url e.g. driver is available on "http://radimbukovsky.cz/extra/geckodriver"

I have tried many url variations but I have not been successfull.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: './src/test/java/drivers/geckodriver'});
```

Comment: also try `file:src./blah`

Comment: thank you, it works fine... I have forgotten the dot in the beginning of the path..